# Why doesn't my component re-render when state changes (redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning redux and i'm making a sort of pokedex app where i fetch 20 pokemons from pokeapi.co at a time. When the page changes a new list of 20 pokemons is fetched. The problem is that while state changes to the new pokemons, they don't actually render.

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const offset = useSelector(state => state.offset);
  const limit = useSelector(state => state.limit);

  useEffect(() => {
    //FETCHES 20 OBJECTS THAT CONTAIN AN URL TO AN INDIVIDUAL POKEMON
    dispatch(fetchPokemons(limit, offset));
  }, [limit, offset, dispatch]);

...

return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#222222' }}>
      <Notification />
      <AppBarPokemon />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/pokemons">
          <PokemonsDisplay CapsFirstLetter={CapsFirstLetter}/>
        </Route>
...
```

PokemonsDisplay.js

```
const PokemonsDisplay = ({ CapsFirstLetter }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const pokemons = useSelector(state => state.pokemons);
    console.log(pokemons);
    const pageSize = 20;
    const totalCount = 898;

    const handleClick = (p) => {
        dispatch(getOnePokemon(p));
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
                {pokemons && (
                    <Grid container spacing={3}>
                        {pokemons.map(p => (
                    <Grid item xs={3} key={p.name} className={classes.gridItem} component={Link} onClick={() => handleClick(p)} to={`/pokemons/${p.name}`} data-cy={`pokemon-button-${p.name}`}>
                            <Paper className={classes.paper && classes.color} elevation={10}>
                                <p className={classes.p}>#{p.id}</p>
                                <p className={classes.p}>{CapsFirstLetter(p.name)}</p>
                                {p.sprites.other["dream_world"]["front_default"] !== null ? 
                                <img className={classes.image} alt={`${p.name}'s sprite`} src={p.sprites.other["dream_world"]["front_default"]}/> : 
                                <img className={classes.image} alt={`${p.name}'s sprite`} src={p.sprites.other["official-artwork"]["front_default"]}/>}
                            </Paper>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
                    </Grid>
                )}
            <Pagination
                totalCount={totalCount} 
                pageSize={pageSize}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

pokemonsReducer.js

```
import getPokemons from '../services/pokemons';
import axios from 'axios';
import { loadPokemonsFromLS, savePokemonsList } from '../utils/localStoragePokemons';

const pokemonsReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    console.log('state is:', state)
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INIT_POKEMONS':
            return action.data;
        default:
            return state;
    };
};

export const fetchPokemons = (limit, offset) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const pokemons = loadPokemonsFromLS(limit, offset);
            dispatch({
                type: 'INIT_POKEMONS',
                data: pokemons
            });
        } catch (error) {
            const pokemons = await getPokemons.getPokemons(limit, offset);
            let pokemonsArray = [];
            let pokemonsObject = {};
            pokemons.results.forEach(async (r, i) => {
                //FETCHES EACH POKEMON URL AND STORES ITS DATA ON pokemons STATE
                const pokemonNow = await axios.get(r.url);
                pokemonsArray.push(pokemonNow.data);
                pokemonsObject[i] = pokemonNow.data
            });
            savePokemonsList(limit, offset, pokemonsObject);
            dispatch({
                type: 'INIT_POKEMONS',
                data: pokemonsArray
            });
        }
    };
};

export default pokemonsReducer;
```

I have tried to `dispatch({ data: [...pokemons] })`
But it doesnt work.

Also i forgot to add. When i go to my component that is routed to '/' and then back to '/pokemons' they render.

Edit: I think i'm getting there.

i changed the reducer function so that it gets called independently from the dispatch, the problem is that now the action doesn't get fired xD.

```
export const fetchEverything = async (limit, offset) => {
    try {
        const pokemons = loadPokemonsFromLS(limit, offset);
        initPokemons(pokemons);
    } catch (error) {
        const pokemonsData = await getPokemons.getPokemons(limit, offset);
        let pokemons = [];
        let pokemonsObject = {};
        console.log(pokemonsData)
        pokemonsData.results.forEach(async (r, i) => {
            //FETCHES EACH POKEMON URL AND STORES ITS DATA ON pokemons STATE
            const pokemonNow = await axios.get(r.url);
            pokemonsObject[i] = pokemonNow.data;
            //console.log([pokemonNow.data][0]);
            pokemons.push(pokemonNow.data);
        });
        console.log(pokemons);
        console.log(pokemonsObject);
        savePokemonsList(limit, offset, pokemonsObject);
        initPokemons(pokemons);
    };
};

export const initPokemons = (pokemons) => {
    return dispatch => dispatch({ type: 'INIT_POKEMONS', pokemons: pokemons })
};

const pokemonsReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INIT_POKEMONS':
            console.log(action);
            const newState = action.pokemons
            return newState;
        default:
            return state;
    };
};
```

Comment: Start adding some `console.log`'s. Especially if it works on one machine at not another.

Comment: i have a subscription on my store.js that logs store.getState().pokemons and a console.log on my display component. Thats how i know my state changes. Where else should i add them?

Answer (score 1):

It happens due to redux state mutation, you can resolve this issue using immer as stated in redux documentation as well. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer